# aws cloudformation - Launch ec2 instance in my vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

```
  EC2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetAPublic
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      ImageId: !FindInMap 
        - AWSRegionArch2AMI
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - !FindInMap 
          - AWSInstanceType2Arch
          - !Ref InstanceType
          - Arch       
  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH access via port 22
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: !Ref SSHLocation
```

If I remove "SubnetId:! Ref SubnetAPublic" from the EC2Instance entry, it works fine.

What is the reason?

[Full Code]
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/syLee1111/test/master/public%20and%20private%20subnets%20in%20two%20availability%20zones.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. That's because the subnet is part of the vpc , but your security group is not.

It should work if you create the security group inside the vpc.

You can do so by setting `VpcId` parameter to the security group.

also you should use `SecurityGroupIds` instead of `SecurityGroups`

```
EC2Instance:
  Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
  Properties:
    InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
    SubnetId: !Ref SubnetAPublic
    SecurityGroupIds:
      - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
    KeyName: !Ref KeyName
    ImageId: !FindInMap 
      - AWSRegionArch2AMI
      - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
      - !FindInMap 
        - AWSInstanceType2Arch
        - !Ref InstanceType
        - Arch
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added `VpcId: !Ref VPC` to `InstanceSecurityGroup:` but it's still the same.

Comment: The parameter groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: b736cf6d-35e5-49e7-b583-ee75370353b3)

Comment: updated the answer, you should use `SecurityGroupIds` instead of `SecurityGroups`

Comment: happy to help ;)